# Spring MVC application with multiple application context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

Can we write an application using Spring MVC that will support multiple sub-contexts with the same backend controllers/services?

Something like a job website which will show jobs per country as sub-context and each sub-context will have its own database.

```
    https://www.example.com/us         -- database 'jobs-us'
    https://www.example.com/uk         -- database 'jobs-uk'
    https://www.example.com/au etc     -- database 'jobs-au'
```

And a common login context to support authentication.

```
    https://www.example.com/login      -- database 'jobs-user'
```

All the contexts have the same functionality so I've to use the same controller & services.

Of course, I can develop a website and deploy multiple WAR's per context (us.war, uk.war, au.war etc). Instead would love to have a single application with multiple sub-contexts.

Comment: My first thought would be to use injected data access `@Component`s that implement an interface. Then the controller or service could just use the implementing `@Component` that is applicable for the country.

Comment: Multitenant database can help you... If you want to know how it works just look any global services provider when they ask you to choose region. Good example is slack where they provide you private workspace(an example)

Comment: How it works? You will have a master database which will store all connection details with tenant id, so when you will switch to ,say au, it will pass db credentials present is country code au. And for easy way pass this inside headres so you don't have to add it everytime with request and so your other APIs will perform normally. If need more details do let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest instead of having multiple war file specific to country code. You can have one war file with one rest endpoint having country code. I mean you have something like this.

```
GET https://www.example.com/{countryCode}
```

It is a rest call where you are passing like UK, US etc. Based upon the country code, you can pull the job details specific to that country.

Besides, your login functionality should not be tightly coupled with country code.

Answer (score 0):

You can look here https://github.com/ashif14/spring-web-mvc-project

I've created a small sample web app with 2 different contexts

1. Secure context, mapped to (/s/*)
2. Web Context, mapped to (/*)

You can also make necessary changes based on your requirements.